# Joining multiple tables with same identifier & pulling in a field based on shared identifier

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

The context: a health care clinic has 2 tables: one on patient visits, and one on patient appointments. They are not 1:1; it is possible to have an appointment without a visit, or to have a visit without an appointment. The identifier for both tables is the encounter ID, enc_ID. I'm trying to outer join these tables together and to pull in patient names.

A boiled-down example of the visit table (V):

```
enc_ID         Visit_date     Patient_ID
1              2018-06-01     10
2              2018-06-02     11
```

And the appointment data (A):

```
enc_ID         Appointment_time          Patient_ID
1              2018-06-01 13:00          10
3              2018-06-03 14:00          12
```

Outer-joining these on visit_ID would produce something like:

```
enc_ID      V.Visit_date   A.Appointment_time   V.Patient_ID   A.Patient_ID
1           2018-06-01     2018-06-01 13:00     10             10
2           2018-06-02     NULL                 11             NULL
3           NULL           2018-06-03 14:00     NULL           12
```

Say I want to basically combine V.Patient_ID and A.Patient_ID, and pull in patient name from another table (P), joined on Patient_ID. The desired output:

```
enc_ID      V.Visit_date   A.Appointment_time   Patient_ID   Patient_Name
1           2018-06-01     2018-06-01 13:00     10           Patient A
2           2018-06-02     NULL                 11           Patient B
3           NULL           2018-06-03 14:00     13           Patient C
```

How might this be accomplished? I'm probably missing something obvious, but I don't see how I can join in P.Patient_Name without having to join it to either V.Patient_ID or A.Patient_ID, either of which would result in null patient names.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as enc_ID in both tables are not nullable, you can combine those fields with a `COALESCE`:

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(V.Patient_ID, A.Patient_ID) AS enc_ID,
    V.Visit_date,
    A.Appointment_time,
    COALESCE(V.Patient_ID, A.Patient_ID) AS Patient_ID,
    P.Patient_Name
FROM V 
FULL JOIN A ON V.enc_ID = A.enc_ID
INNER JOIN P 
    ON P.Patient_ID = V.Patient_ID
    OR P.Patient_ID = A.Patient_ID
    -- ON P.Patient_ID = COALESCE(V.Patient_ID, A.Patient_ID) also works
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ISNULL` to join table P.

```
...(Your outer join query)
LEFT JOIN P
ON P.Patient_ID = ISNULL(V.Patient_ID, A.PatientID)
```